# Webscraping with selenium cannot import "Service" from

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, service, webdriver, updates

So supposedly webdriver is not installed because the most recent error call back is in line 2 and that's where I tried to install webdriver, here is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gabbles\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\greatness.py", line 2, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  File "C:\Users\gabbles\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.edge import webdriver
  File "C:\Users\gabbles\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .service import Service
  File "C:\Users\gabbles\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\service.py", line 6, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.edge import Service as sc
ImportError: cannot import name 'Service' from 'selenium.webdriver.edge' (C:\Users\gabbles\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\__init__.py)
```

my question is how come web driver is not working? and the installations are right here everything os up to date but I wonder if my code isn't?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.edge import Service as sc
```